# Error Reference when assigning value to asp:textbox

Tags: c#, jquery

Hi everyone I have been having a lot of problems with Jquery right now and ended coming here to search for the problem I have, I found nothing that could help me so I decided to ask at once.

So I was able to bring the value of the input by using this line of code:

```
 $('#ClienteDialog').find('input[id$=txtAddCliente]').val()
```

But now it won't assign that value to the textbox used to store the value and use it on the code behind, it gives the following error:

```
 ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
 $('input[id$=txtAddType]').val() = $('#ClienteDialog').find('input[id$=txtAddCliente]').val();
```

And I really can't find anything bad about this.

Edit:  Hi again I tried your solution Harshit Tailor gave, but at the end it didn't work, it only seems to do it but when I check if it works by using the next code:

```
$('input[id$=txtAddType]').text($('#ClienteDialog').find('input[id$=txtAddCliente]').val());
                        $('input[id$=lblTypeAdd]').val("1");
                        var a1 = $('#ClienteDialog').find('input[id$=txtAddCliente]').val();
                        var a2 = $('input[id$=txtAddType]').text();
                        var a3 = $('input[id$=txtAddType]').val();
                        var a4 = $('input[id$=lblTypeAdd]').text();
                        var a5 = $('input[id$=lblTypeAdd]').val();
```

It brings in each var:

```
a1 = "Toyota" //<- This is the value I input
a2 = Undefined
a3 = ""
a4 = Undefined
a5 = ""
```

Is there anyway to put the input value into the text value of the labels and textbox mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('input[id$=txtAddType]').val($('#ClienteDialog').find('input[id$=txtAddCliente]').val());
```

Comment: pata nahi..phone kar dena..sir ko

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29444/discussion-between-harshit-tailor-and-ankush-jain)

Comment: Thanks for your awnser it worked perfectly but when it gets to the line with __doPostBack('input[id$=btnAddConfig]', "OnClick"); it doesn't do the onClick action of the button, any idea???

Comment: @AndresScarpone don't know.. you have to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[id$=txtAddType]').val($('#ClienteDialog').find('input[id$=txtAddCliente]').val());
```

see `.val()` docs -- >  http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
.val( value )
```

> Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.